# stopForeground(true) called on a Service, gets me a classname null issue

Tags: android, android-intent, service, classname, foreground-service

This is how I start my service:

```
    public void startService(){
        if (!isRunningInForeground()) {
            Log.i("#foregroundservice", "Starting service");
            bindIntent = new Intent(PSLocationService.this, PSLocationService.class);
            startService(bindIntent);
        }
    }
```

I do this on the onStartCommand:

```
   @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PSLocationService.startId = startId;
    if (PSApplicationClass.getInstance().isAutoPilotAllowed() || PSTrip.getActiveTrip() != null) {
        Log.i("#foregroundservice", "onStartCommand");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PSTimelineFragmentsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.passenger_name))
                .setContentText(getText(R.string.getStarted_switch_on_toplabel))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1338, notification);
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

And when I disconnect from googleApiClient, I want to stop it like this:

```
  if (isRunningInForeground()) {
        Log.i("#foregroundservice", "Stopping service: " + bindIntent);
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }
```

It always crashes at `stopForeground(true)` method with this error:

```
11-10 12:59:50.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10731): java.lang.NullPointerException: class name is null
11-10 12:59:50.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10731):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:114)
11-10 12:59:50.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10731):    at android.app.Service.stopForeground(Service.java:671)
11-10 12:59:50.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10731):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.core.tracking.PSLocationService.disconnectLocationClient(PSLocationService.java:272)
```

Comment: Where do you call startService?

Comment: from my ApplicationClass

Comment: comment stopSelf (after stopForeground) and let me know if it crashes again

Comment: BTW in: `new Intent(PSLocationService.this, PSLocationService.class);` why did you pass `PSLocationService.this`?  why not App context (this)?

Comment: I guess your service just starts in foreground  and when you try to stopSelf it throws an exception

Comment: no, it crashes in stopForeground. I already removed stopSelf. Also, if I leave stopSelf, and remove stopForeground, it doesn't crash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did manage to make it work by calling `stopForeground(true)` from an activity class, and not my ApplicationClass.
Also instead of stopForeground, i do this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, PSLocationService.class);
context.stopService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Sharing on example of a logcat or a crash in Firebase might help trying to figure out why that happens :)
But yea, just downvote an answer to a question 4 years ago, cause it doesn't work for you. What are you even doing here? Google recommends using a WorkManager with setForegroundAsync or a JobSheduler, Service is an old antique class, and IntentService has been deprecated with Android 11 so if this does not work for you, drop entirely your Service logic and bring your app on par with 2021 by using best practices ^_^